# Eclipse unable to locate file-- FileNotFoundException on File object usage

Tags: java, file, filenotfoundexception

When I attempt to access a File object in Java using Eclipse, the system sends a FileNotFoundException whenever the file is accessed. I have created the file manually and placed it within Eclipse's file browser. The file does have content, so the problem isn't that it's empty. I am initializing the File with

```
File file = new File(this.getClass().getResource("save.txt").toString());
```

and accessing it with

```
PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(file);
```

which sends the error. The stacktrace flows back through nothing except a path of initializations that create this class. The exception is

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\Users\Nathaniel\Downloads\ERPGE-Global%20Equestria%20Workspace\Swarm\bin\main\save.txt (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

What could be causing this error, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Do you have whitespaces in your path? If that is the case does the access also fails on a path without whitespaces?

Comment: I bet your path is not correct somehow. Try to print out the path of your file using `System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());`

Comment: I've managed to come up with sort of a solution. I'm going to prompt the user for the path of the file when they save. Nothing suggested here seems to work, so this is the best I can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide the actual path to the file and get the file Object. Then you can use it.

```
File file = new File("C:\Users\Nathaniel\Downloads\save.txt");
PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(file);
```

EDIT:

Externalising the File Name:

Create a properties file filedetails.properties in the external folder/package.

```
fileName=C:\Users\Nathaniel\Downloads\save.txt
```

Accessing the resource bundle.

```
ResourceBundle b=ResourceBundle.getBundle("external.filedetails") ;
String fileName=b.getString("fileName");
File file=new File(fileName);
```

Comment: I'm attempting to make this a portable application-- it's intended for use on multiple platforms, so a static path won't suffice. Unless I misunderstand, this.getClass().getResource() returns the path to the resource at the listed location, correct? It works for images, so I assumed the same would hold true for text files.

Comment: Portable applications don't use the `File` abstraction in the first place. That's what the classloader's resource mechanism is for.

Comment: you can externalise the file name using a properties file and fetch it @ runtime. so each platform can have its own value.

Comment: How would I fetch the properties file to list paths without a direct path to the properties file?

Comment: @Baqueta  ,@Passage first you have do the basics. i mean if the program is work on static path you can easily convert it into a dynamic one.

Comment: @Amith Why do it badly the first time when it really isn't difficult to do it properly the first time?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the resource is included in the project's build path.

You can do this in one of two ways:

1. Put it in a folder (e.g. "res") then add that folder to the build path. That way, all the files in the folder will be added to the build path.
2. Put it inside (one of) your source folders. Be aware that if you put it inside a package folder, you'll need to include the relative path to that folder (see below).

Personally I prefer option #1.

**Edit:** You might also find it useful to have sub-directories of the res folder. If you have a file such as *res/images/button.png* and you've added the res folder to the build path, you need to access the file with the string *"images/button.png"*.

**Edit 2:** Fixed some misleading info.

Comment: After adding the file to the build path, I've begun getting errors stating that the selection does not contain a main type, seemingly at random.

Comment: My bad, looks like if you add files individually they get added as libraries. Will edit to fix.

Answer (score 1):

The file needs to be placed in the parent project folder itself and not the source folder. If a file is created without a specified file path, this is where it would be stored.